# How use Oracle ojdbc7 on Github via Travis-CI

Tags: oracle, maven, github, travis-ci, ojdbc

I want use mvn clean install on Travis-CI but my ojdbc7 dependancy is not downloaded because my maven setting do not have the https://maven.oracle.com and login/password

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my local machine is OK because my local .m2 contain .m2\repository\com\oracle\jdbc\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best answer for my question despite any downvote !!!**

I create a sample on github with all explications: https://github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

**Your pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <username>${OTN_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${OTN_PASSWORD}</password>
            <configuration>
                <basicAuthScope>
                    <host>ANY</host>
                    <port>ANY</port>
                    <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
                </basicAuthScope>
                <httpConfiguration>
                    <all>
                        <params>
                            <property>
                                <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
                                <value>%b,true</value>
                            </property>
                        </params>
                    </all>
                </httpConfiguration>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you would need to follow the instructions laid out in the following guide:

[Fusion Middleware Developing Applications Using Continuous Integration : Chapter 6 - Configuring the Oracle Maven Repository](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010)

Specifically:

1. Register: https://www.oracle.com/webapps/maven/register/license.html
2. Add the Oracle Maven Repo to your POM:

> ```
> <repositories>
>   <repository>
>     <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
>     <releases>
>       <enabled>true</enabled>
>     </releases>
>     <snapshots>
>       <enabled>false</enabled>
>     </snapshots>
>     <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
>     <layout>default</layout>
>   </repository>
> </repositories>
> <pluginRepositories>
>   <pluginRepository>
>     <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
>     <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
>   </pluginRepository>
> </pluginRepositories>
> ```

3. Make sure your version of http-wagon is using 2.8 or above
4. Then configure the repository OTN login in your Maven settings.xml

> ```
>  <server>
>     <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
>     <username>**username**</username>
>     <password>**password**</password>
>     <configuration>
>       <basicAuthScope>
>         <host>ANY</host>
>         <port>ANY</port>
>         <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
>       </basicAuthScope>
>       <httpConfiguration>
>         <all>
>           <params>
>             <property>
>               <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
>               <value>%b,true</value>
>             </property>
>           </params>
>         </all>
>       </httpConfiguration>
>     </configuration>
>   </server>
> ```